# Aplicaciones como discord y figma no abren por Electron (Node.js)

Tags: windows

En estos ultimos dias he tenido un problema a la hora de querer ejecutar discord y figma en mi laptop.
Realmente no se de donde venga el problema arraigado, como tal culpo a mi proyecto de electron en el que trabajo actualmente.

Ya que a la hora de querer ejecutarlo me aparece esto:

`[2760:0311/085337.840:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(993)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741515 [2760:0311/085337.865:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(993)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741515 [2760:0311/085337.874:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(993)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741515 [2760:0311/085337.884:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(993)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741515 [2760:0311/085337.892:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(993)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741515 [2760:0311/085337.901:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(993)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741515 [2760:0311/085337.910:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(993)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741515 [2760:0311/085337.918:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(993)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741515 [2760:0311/085337.927:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(993)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=-1073741515 [2760:0311/085337.927:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(448)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.`

Para solucionarlo de manera rapida en mi proyecto solo integre estas dos lineas de codigo para que corriera el programa:

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('no-sandbox');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('in-process-gpu');
```

Con esto ya pude correr mi programa, pero ahora Discord y Figma no responden, ni siquiera abren.
Alguna solucion?
Ya probe actualizando mi windows y no se soluciona, asi como borrar la cache de mis aplicaciones.